# Same UIViewController being loaded from 2 different sources but with different results

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

In my application I have 2 separate ways to get to the same UIViewController, on way is to go through 2 parent ViewControllers created using the storyboard and this way works perfectly just passing and id through each segue transition.

The other way (Which is what I need help with) goes directly from a button pressed on the RootViewController, it also just passes the id to a customly defined object called Event. The code for each transition is below:

**From the segue:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender 
{
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Event *event = [nEventList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    EventInfo *eventInfo = segue.destinationViewController; //Create new ViewController
    eventInfo.eventID = event.id;
}
```

**From the button:**

```
- (void)FeaturedPressedAction:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    int tag = button.tag;
    EventInfo *eventInfo = [[EventInfo alloc] init]; //Create new ViewController
    eventInfo.eventID = @"1"; //There is an event with id '1'
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:eventInfo animated:YES];
}
```

**And the code to set up the ViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"title.png"];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

    SingletonClass* myapp = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    events = [myapp getEvents];

    // Loop to filter out the events that Do not have this ID
    Event *event;
    BOOL found = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < [events count]; i++) {
        if(!found){
            event = [events objectAtIndex:i];
            if([event.id isEqualToString: eventID]){
                found = true;
                NSLog(@"Found the event with title %@", event.title);
            }
        }
    }

    self.eventTitle.text = event.title;
    self.eventLocation.text = event.location;
    self.eventDate.text = event.date;
    self.eventTime.text = @"22:00";
    self.eventDescription.text = event.details; 
}
```

It finds the event fine as I can see with the NSLog's left in there, just none of the view loads when coming from the button press. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than alloc your `EventInfo*`, you should instantiate it from your storyboard instead.

So in your `FeaturedPressedAction` replace the initialisation line with:

```
EventInfo *eventInfo = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"..."];
```

And make sure you identify the ViewController in Interface Builder with the same identifier.  Replace ... with something meaningful.

Comment: A pleasure, you posted all the right code and explained the problem well - always makes it easier to help!